# Creating a Website as a Beginner. Costs Calculating for the Customer

Tags: salary, websites, self-employment

I've got an "offer" to create a Website with an ecommerce Shop. I did not work much in the Webdevelopment and the customer asked me of course how much it will cost. I replied that I've to calculate it when I've got the specification.

So, my Problem is, that I do not know how many hours it will take to develop the site and what I could claim per working hour because im a "Beginner" in Webdevelopment...

Do you Guys have any Hints? A reference Point?

//EDIT
Im not an absolute beginner. 
Ofc do i know the usage of html, css, php,... Also I've worked some months with Joomla and WP, but I never had to calculate the needed effort on my own

Comment: This question sounds like it would be better at [Freelancing StackExchange](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "I did not work much in the Webdevelopment" - so why I someone offering to pay you for such? Do you know of your lack of experience? If not, and/or you re not doing it for a friend, I cannot see this ending well

Comment: From your question, you are not ready to be able to accept this mission as a freelancer. Estimating relies on personal experience when it comes to web development => You ARE your OWN reference point. Some people will take 10 minutes to do something whereas others will need an hour. Other than that, freelancing fees are usualy counted per day and not per hour depending on your skill, productivity and the value you deliver. IMHO you need more training/experience to carry this mission according to the question you asked.

Comment: Im sorry about choosing the wrong StackExchange Topic. So I guess it would be better to do it more or less for free or for A testimonial.

Comment: @JohnDoe Or just not do it at all

Comment: $10,000 minimum !

Comment: The three most common pricing models are Time & Materials, Fixed Price, and Milestone. T&M you get paid by the hour, Fixed Price is exactly what it sounds like, and Milestone, you get paid by delivering pre-agreed upon milestones. I'd go for the last if I were you, but of course I'm not you. Do some reading on each model and see which one makes sense for the project. Good luck

Comment: To my fellow Workplace dwellers: Suggesting that the OP does not take on a piece of work because he's never done it before is not terribly constructive. It's up to his client to decide if OP is skilled enough to do the project, not up to you.

Comment: **Never, _ever_ work for free. A "reference" is not payment.**. If you do work for free, you lose _all_ negotiating power and you'll have to agree to things at least as hideous as working for free in the future, because you've shown how low you're willing to go. If you don't feel confident, don't do the project, but if you do, **don't do it for free**. And finally, before you start doing _anything_, **sign a contract**. Get a template off the Internet or write down in a piece of paper **what** you will deliver, **when**, and **how much** you'll get paid for it.

Comment: @JohnDoe You said this is an "ecommerce shop" website.  In other words, your code will be at least partially responsible for **recording payment information** and **charging people money.**  This is very different from simple WordPress sites, and a fast-track to lawsuits if you screw up, so I would seriously consider not doing it at all until you've had more experience with that sort of thing.  Building a website like this as an employee in a company offers you personally some measure of liability protection which you won't have as a freelancer.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not know how many hours it will take to develop the site and what I could claim per working hour because im a Beginner in Webdevelopment...

That's a bit worrying.

If you're really a beginner in web dev and have no experience in doing this sort of thing previously, then you shouldn't be taking on something like this on your own in the first place - it's a bit of a recipe for disaster.

Try to work with an existing experienced dev for a while before going solo, or get a job as a junior web developer so as to build up your skills and experience.

We all have to start somewhere of course, but usually that somewhere isn't jumping into a solo project with no knowledge!

Comment: Thank you very much! Ofc do i know the usage of html, css, php,...Also I've worked some months with Joomla and WP, but I never had to calculate the needed effort on my own.